# Is $K^{n}$ Zariski Hausdorff when $K$ is a finite field?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, finite-fields

Assume  that  $K$ is  a finite field. Is it true to say that $K^{n}$  is  a  Hausdorff topological space with [Zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology)?

Comment: But you clarify what you mean by the Zariski topology on this set?

Comment: The Zariski topology on $K^n$, where $K$ is a finite field, is identical to the discrete topology.  The discrete topology is always Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Zariski topology on $K^n$ is discrete if $K$ is finite.  If $K$ is any field, then for any point $p=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in K^n$, $\{p\}$ is the vanishing set of the ideal $(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)$ and hence Zariski closed.  If all singletons are closed, then all finite sets are closed, which means that all subsets of $K^n$ are closed if $K$ is finite.